# laravel 5 how to pass data to controller to model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am new for `Laravel 5` and learning. Now I have created login form and I want to check if user is valid(match user from table) and take some action.

Right now I am getting all form data from `controller (AdminLoginController.php)`. Now I don't know how to pass to model for check if user is exists or not.

### view (login.blade.php)

```
//I have used this form action {{ URL::to('administrator/userAuthentication') }}

<form name="frmLogin" action="{{ URL::to('administrator/userAuthentication') }}" method="post">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username"class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php /*<div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="checkbox icheck">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"> Remember Me
                </label>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.col -->*/ ?>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Login</button>
        </div><!-- /.col -->
    </div>
</form>
```

### controller (AdminLoginController.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt for admin user.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function userAuthentication(Request $request)
    {
        echo "<pre>";
            return $request;
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

model (AdminLoginModel.php)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AdminLoginModel extends Model
{

    public function checkAuthentication()
    {
        // code
    }

}
```

I don't know I am doing right way or not so need your suggestion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply pass parameters to your models. In your controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\AdminLoginModel;

class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt for admin user.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function userAuthentication(Request $request)
    {
        $admin_model = new AdminLoginModel();
        $admin_model->checkAuthentication($request);
    }
}
```

In your model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AdminLoginModel extends Model
{

    public function checkAuthentication($request)
    {
        // Do something with $request
        $request->input('username');
    }

}
```

Comment: But as Pedram marandi suggested, checkout the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication. First the docs seems overhelming, but checkout the **basics** and authentication in **services**

Comment: Thanks I will check laravel docs but can you please tell me that my coding style is proper or not for laravel?

Answer (score -4):

Hello and welcome to Laravel,

Don't worry about pass data between your model and controller and so views laravel have great MVC design so just you need do it right.

You are really good, but it's better to start learning laravel from laravel [Documents](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1)  your code is out of laravel standard and signature for example creating model like this.

laravel Have great [Authentication](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication) service. 
at first you have to learn about Controllers, Models, Eloquent, Requests and in this case Authentication service.

for example you have to create general Model for Users and then check Administrator permission :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{

}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to OP's question, just you telling OP to go look somewhere else for an answer.

Comment: I suggested laravel documents :) question is so newbe so need to learn documentation at first. @dinsdale